# Finding the asymptotic behavior of a function defined implicitly

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, implicit-function

I encountered this when trying to solve a number theory problem. I have two variables $x,y$ related by

$$(\ln(x))^{y+1}=(\ln(xy))^y$$

and I want to know how big $y(x)$ is as $x\to\infty$. Ideally I want to know that $y(x)\sim\ln(x)$ or $y(x)\sim \sqrt{x}$ or whatever it is. But if that's not possible, a tight lower bound would suffice.

I've messed with this expression enough that I managed to convince myself it isn't possible to isolate either variable, except maybe using something like Lambert's W function, and even that I wasn't able to do. So the remaining alternative is to try to solve it as a problem about an implicit function. This sounds like something that is possible with standard calculus tools.

Comment: using $ \log(x)+1\sim \log(x)$ and $\log( x  \log(x))\sim \log(x)$ it seems that $y=\log(x)$ balances both sides in the big $x$ limit. my guess is actually that $y\sim \log(x)+1+o(1)$ but i haven't attempted that calcukations.

Comment: @asgeige. Just a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that $y>1$ and $x >e$. Note that your equation is equivalent to
$$
\log x = \left( {1 + \frac{{\log y}}{{\log x}}} \right)^y .
$$
From this,
$$
\log x = \left( {1 + \frac{{\log y}}{{\log x}}} \right)^y  \le e^{y\frac{{\log y}}{{\log x}}} ,
$$
i.e., $\log x\log \log x \le y\log y$. This implies $y \ge \log x$. Therefore,
$$
\log x = \left( {1 + \frac{{\log y}}{{\log x}}} \right)^y  \ge \left( {1 + \frac{{\log \log x}}{{\log x}}} \right)^y ,
$$
i.e.,
$$
\frac{{\log \log x}}{{\log \left( {1 + \frac{{\log \log x}}{{\log x}}} \right)}} \ge y.
$$ The left-hand side is $\log x +\mathcal{O}(\log \log x)$. Thus, we can also see that $y(x)=\log x +\mathcal{O}(\log \log x)$ as $x \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

To make things easier to handle, start letting $xy=z$ and solve for $y$. In the resulting expression, reset $z=xy$ to face the implicit function
$$F(x,y)=y \log \left(\frac{\log (x y)}{\log (x)}\right)-\log (\log (x))$$ Finding its zero does not make any problem using Newton method since, using the implicit function theorem
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{(y+1) \log (x y)-y \log (x)}{x \log (x) \left(1+\log (x y) \log
   \left(\frac{\log (x y)}{\log (x)}\right)\right)}$$

Now, for the computation, let $\color{red}{x=e^k}$. This makes the equation to be
$$\color{blue}{y \log \left(1+\frac{\log (y)}{k}\right)-\log (k)=0}$$
Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & y \\
 1 &  1.00000\\
 2 &  2.14477 \\
 3 &  3.28784 \\
 4 &  4.39968 \\
 5 &  5.49064 \\
 6 &  6.56722 \\
 7 &  7.63335 \\
 8 &  8.69156 \\
 9 &  9.74355 \\
10 & 10.7905\\
 20 &  21.1086 \\
 30 &  31.3002 \\
 40 &  41.4378 \\
 50 &  51.5453 \\
 60 &  61.6335 \\
 70 &  71.7083 \\
 80 &  81.7732 \\
 90 &  91.8306 \\
 100 &  101.882 \\
 200 &  202.221 \\
 300 &  302.421 \\
 400 &  402.562 \\
 500 &  502.672 \\
 600 &  602.762 \\
 700 &  702.838 \\
 800 &  802.904 \\
 900 &  902.962 \\
 1000 &  1003.01
\end{array}
\right)$$ which do not need much comments.

Notice that $e^{1000}=1.97\times 10^{434}$.

In fact making one single iteration of Newton method with $y_0=k$, we have
$$\color{red}{y_1=k+\frac{(k+\log (k)) \left(\log (k)-k \log \left(1+\frac{\log
   (k)}{k}\right)\right)}{(k+\log (k)) \log \left(1+\frac{\log (k)}{k}\right)+1}}$$

For $k=10$, this simple expression gives $y=10.7984$ and, for $k=1000$, it gives $y=1003.01$.

Expanded as series for large values of $k$
$$y_1=k+\frac{\log ^2(k)}{2 (\log (k)+1)}\Bigg[1-\frac{(\log (k)-2) \log (k)}{6 k (\log (k)+1)} +O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\Bigg]$$

Looking at this last result, there is tight upper bound
$$y < y_*=k+\frac 12 \log(k)$$ starting Newton iteration with this starting point, we should converge without any overshoot of the solution since $f(y_*)\,f''(y_*) >0$ (Darboux theorem).

If, if the "blue" formula, we make inside the first logarithm $y=y_*$, we end with tight bounds
$$ k+\frac 12 \log(k)-\frac 12 <y < k+\frac 12 \log(k)$$